# Display photos in different UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, ios-camera

In my test app, I have two buttons (takePhoto1 and takePhoto2) and two UIImageViews (photo1View and photo2View). The first button takes a photo and displays it in the first image view. The second button takes another photo, and is supposed to display it in the second image view. However, for some reason second photo is displayed in photoView1 instead of photoView2.

I haven't implemented any code to save the photos yet, so I'm not worried about the photos persisting in the image views.

What I do need to figure out is how to make sure when the second photo is taken, it is displayed in the appropriate view. Here is what I have so far:

```
//Take photo1 and display in top image view
- (void)takePhoto1;
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    if ([self.capturedImages count] > 0)
    {
        if ([self.capturedImages count] == 1)
        {
            // Camera took a single picture.
            [self.photo1View setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
        // To be ready to start again, clear the captured images array.
        [self.capturedImages removeAllObjects];
    }

    self.imagePickerController = nil;
}




//Take photo2 and display in bottom image view
- (void)takePhoto2;
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    if ([self.capturedImages count] > 0)
    {
        if ([self.capturedImages count] == 1)
        {
            // Camera took a single picture.
            [self.photo2View setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:1]];
        }
        // To be ready to start again, clear the captured images array.
        [self.capturedImages removeAllObjects];
    }

    self.imagePickerController = nil;
}
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your questions an couldn't help my self to solve it in my way. If I had same problem as yours I would have solved it in this way:

Consider, button's tag is same as, imageView tag.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imageViews;

@property int tag;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    _tag = ((UIButton *)sender).tag;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];


}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerDelegate Methods
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    [[self getImageView:_tag] setImage:image];

}

- (UIImageView *) getImageView : (int) tag{
    for (UIImageView *imageView in _imageViews) {
        if (imageView.tag == tag) {
            return imageView;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}


@end
```

Here you can [check this as working project here](https://github.com/rptwsthi/DeveloperHelpWorkspace).

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! The example project was quite helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check your storyboard or xib to see if "`photo2View`" is really connected to your outlet.

I suspect the UIImageView for "`photo1View`" is also connected to "`photo2View`".

p.s. you should also change this line in your @implementation:

```
- (void)takePhoto2;
```

to this:

```
- (void)takePhoto2
```

semi-colons should only come after method declarations in your .h file.

Comment: Hey @Michael, 
Yes, it looks like "photo2View" is connected to my outlet. I did just check; the UIImageView for "photo1View" isn't connected to "photo2View".

Thank you for the semi-colon correction! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Does your code work? I find two issues -

Issue 1 - This should crash as `capturedImages` has one element according to second `if` check but you are accessing second element in the array while setting the imageView.

```
if ([self.capturedImages count] == 1)
        {
            // Camera took a single picture.
            [self.photo2View setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Issue 2 - Since you are clearing the `self.capturedImages`, this should have thrown you can exception in second method.

```
[self.photo2View setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Comment: Hi Vikram, yes, my code seems to work (no crashes or thrown exceptions). I did get a warning (shown below): 


Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <CameraViewController: 0x1752fc40> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Comment: So how about [self.photo2View setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]];

Comment: Hi @auspicious99, I just tried that; didn't seem to notice any change between 

[self.photo2View setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:1]];

and

[self.photo2View setImage:[self.capturedImages objectAtIndex:0]];

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly connect button 1 to takePhoto1 and button 2 to takePhoto2? Maybe button 2 is also doing takePhoto1?

Comment: Yep, just checked; each button is connected to the appropriate method :/

Comment: Hmm, another thing you could try, to narrow it down, is to put NSLog statements in both methods, to make sure that the correct method is being called in each case

Comment: Another possibility, maybe somewhere else you accidentally set self.photo2View to self.photo1View?

Comment: Doesn't appear that I did, I thought be that 
        [self.capturedImages removeAllObjects];
was causing the problem, but if I comment it out, the app crashes.